# Creating a new rrd database based on an existing one

Tags: clone, reverse-engineering, rrdtool, rrd

I have some old rrdtool databases, for which the exact creation recipe has long been since lost. I need to create a new database with the same characteristics as the current ones. I've dumped a couple of old databases and pored over the contents but I'm not sure how to interpret the metadata. I think it appears in the following stanzas

```
<cf> AVERAGE </cf>
<pdp_per_row> 360 </pdp_per_row> <!-- 1800 seconds -->
<xff> 5.0000000000e-01 </xff>
```

There are four such stanzas, which correspond to the way I recall the round-robin cascading was set up. Has anyone already done this, or can give me pointers as to how to clone a new empty rrd database from an existing one? Or show me where I missed this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rrdtools' [rrdinfo](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdinfo.en.html) is your friend!

It will tell you how the rrd file's data source(s) and archive(s) were created.  Example

```
$ rrdtool info random.rrd
filename = "random.rrd"
rrd_version = "0001"
step = 300
last_update = 955892996
ds[a].type = "GAUGE"
ds[a].minimal_heartbeat = 600
ds[a].min = NaN
ds[a].max = NaN
ds[a].last_ds = "UNKN"
ds[a].value = 2.1824421548e+04
ds[a].unknown_sec = 0
ds[b].type = "GAUGE"
ds[b].minimal_heartbeat = 600
ds[b].min = NaN
ds[b].max = NaN
ds[b].last_ds = "UNKN"
ds[b].value = 3.9620838224e+03
ds[b].unknown_sec = 0
rra[0].cf = "AVERAGE"
rra[0].pdp_per_row = 1
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].value = nan
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].unknown_datapoints = 0
rra[0].cdp_prep[1].value = nan
rra[0].cdp_prep[1].unknown_datapoints = 0
```

Comment: I think you mean 'info' rather than 'rrdinfo'. But thanks, that's a start.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote :P  Follow the link and you'll see what I mean.  Yes, at the command line it is invoked with "rrdtool info", but the it is named on its reference page 'rrdinfo'.   Splitting hairs, I guess.  ALSO, the tool gives you a 1:1 parameter list for your rrd creation. Easy!

Comment: This doesn't really, truly answer the question, but since it's the only response, you get the point :)

Answer (score 5):

I use the command [rrdcreate](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcreate.en.html). It can create a new rrd based in an existing one.  The -t parameter indicate a existing rrd as template.

rrdcreate  new.rrd -t existing.rrd

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: also use `--source` if you want to preserve data too (and not only structure)

Answer (score 2):

You can try use the clone script described [here.](http://code.google.com/p/python-rrd-schema-parse/source/browse/rrdinfo-parser.py) It's very basic but it works for simple rrd files. I used it to figure out a schema that was generated by munin. I needed to insert old data into munin so I reverse engineered the schema, set the --start to a date prior to the start of my old data and re-imported data into the rrd.

```
$ python rrdinfo-parser.py -f test.rrd
rrdtool create test.rrd --start 920804400 --step 300 \
DS:speed:COUNTER:600:U:U \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:24 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:6:10 \
```